# Mostrar imagen almacenada en SQLServer en un ImageView (Java, Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, sql

estoy realizando una aplicación en android con sql server y no se como crear la función ByteToImagen en java, es decir en c# y vb.net tenia una función que me tomaba la cadena de bytes[] almacenada en el campo image de sql server, hacía la conversión y me devolvía la imagen. Pero soy nuevo en java y no se como poder lograr este resultado. :(

Comment: Hola Seto, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la información que falta según [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Revisa lo que comenta Mulflar, al menos agrega tu código, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Bitmap getStringToBitmap() {
    if (getString() != null) {
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(getString().getBytes());
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
        return bitmap;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Supongo que a la cadena de bytes del SQL Server accederas a través de alguna petición REST que te devolverá un xml, JSON o similar, getString() será un método que simplemente te de esa cadena de bytes en String.

Con este mñetodo que te pongo obtendrás un Bitmap a partir de esa cadena que luego puedes cargar en un ImageView con la siguiente instrucción.

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(getStringToBitmap());
```

Comment: No todas las preguntas se pueden o se deben contestar. Ahórrate un poco de frustración y evita responder a preguntas que  son inciertas o requieren demasiada orientación para que puedas contestarla completamente. Tienes suficiente reputación para haber dejado esto como un comentario en lugar de como una respuesta. Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: Hola Damián González Fernández, tengo un inconveniente y es que me dice Bad Base 64. Te comento que la función getString() que mencionas la reemplace con mi cadena de bytes[] obtenida del campo image de sql server mediante un ResultSet.

Comment: Damiàn si agregaste una respuesta seria buena idea respondieras lo que comenta Seto, esto para que tu respuesta en verdad sea correcta, porque "Bad Base 64"?

Comment: Perdon @Seto copié y pegué el código de un proyecto personal donde la cadena está codificada en Base64, simplemente quita esa parte, he editado la respuesta.

Comment: Si gracias ya lo resolví. Saludos!